# Given sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, show there exists a set $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, I have been able to use the Axioms of Union and Pairing to create $\{A,B,C,D\}$ by the following method:

1. Form the set $\{A,B\}$ via the Axiom of Pairing.
2. Form the set $\{C,D\}$ via the Axiom of Pairing.
3. Form the set $S=\{\{A,B\},\{C,D\}\}$ via the Axiom of Pairing.
4. Apply the Axiom of Union to $S$ to obtain $P=\{A,B,C,D\}$.

I was able to use a similar method to obtain $\{A,B,C\}$.

I do not see how to use a similar method to obtain $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$.

Comment: Use Pairing to get e.g. $\{ A , E \}$ and then repeat the Union step with it and $P$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah, so just create set $T=\{P,\{A,E\}\}$ and apply Axiom of Union to $T$? If you put this into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I don't see you similar meod to obtain $\{A,B,C\}$.  But can't you make $\{D,E\}$ and then $\{\{A,B,C\}\{D,e\}\}$ and then union to get $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$?  ..... BTW with the axiom of union are you allowed to assume you don't need to know what the union is.  THat is If you $P=\{A,B,C\}$ and $Q = \{B,C,D\}$ the axiom of union would mean you have to have $P\cup Q = \{A,B,C,D\}$? Is that valid?

Comment: @fleablood Answer to your first question is "yes". My brain was not working. As for your second question, the Axiom of Union only works on a set. So if you want $A\cup B$ then you first need a set $S=\{A,B\}$.  The Axiom of Union: "For any set $S$, there exists a set $U$ such that $x\in U$ if and only if $x\in A $ for some $A\in S$".

Comment: See [Axiom of union: Relation to Pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union#Relation_to_Pairing).

Comment: You can use Pairing on $E$ and itself to get the set $\left\{E\right\}$. Using Pairing again, you get the set $\left\{P,\left\{E\right\}\right\}$ and finally the Union gives the desired set.

Comment: @OlegTurcan Yeah for some reason I wasn't able to consider the possibility of including P in a new set. Thanks

Comment: My question about union was about multi-sets.  If you have $\{P,Q\}$ so you have $P\cup Q$ are you allowed to know that $P\cup Q$ is specifically the set $\{A,B,C,D\}$ with those four elements, or does the axiom only allow you to know the union exists that it has $A,B,C$ as well as $B,C,D$ but it doesn't allow you to *know* the set and that it has 4 elements and isn't something like $\{A,B,C,B,C,D\}$.

Comment: @fleablood You need the Axiom of Extensionality to show that $\{A,B,C,D\}=\{A,B,C,B,C,D\}$. Without Axiom of Extensionality, those can be distinct sets.

Comment: The question that I am asking is according to the axiom of union, we know that if we have, say, $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{c,d,e\}$ then know we can create $\{a,b,c\}\cup \{c,d,e\}$.  If the exercise was "create the set $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$" are we allowed to say we are done?  The exercise never said "prove that the set you create is actually $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$" It just said create it.  And we did *create* it when we made $\{a,b,c\}\cup \{c,d,e\}$.  Is that alone enough?  Or do we have to prove that what we created is what we wanted?

Comment: @fleablood You can't create $\{a,b,c\}\cup\{c,d,e\}$ with only the AoU. You also need the AoP to create $\{\{a,b,c\},\{c,d,e\}\}$ before you can apply the AoU to create $\{a,b,c\}\cup\{c,d,e\}$. As for your question, without AoE $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ is not necessarily the same as $\{a,b,c\}\cup\{c,d,e\}$. If you're working within ZF then you have AoE and then it's a simple proof to show $\{a,b,c\}\cup\{c,d,e\}=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$. Many introductory set theory books ask the reader to show $\{x\}=\{x,x\}$, using AoE, for example. You aren't really done the exercise until you've shown equality.